# LeadTrigger error: 'Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'. How to resolve it?

Tags: class, triggers, apex

I am getting the following error:

`LeadTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, The industry field cannot be blank: [] Class.LeadTriggerHandler.afterInsertHandler: line 25, column 1 Trigger.LeadTrigger: line 9, column 1.`

What could be the solution?

I need to save the lead record in salesforce UI.

Answer (score 1):

The "FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION" error means that there is a custom validation rule on the Lead object. When you insert the Lead record, it throws the validation rule error because the Industry field is blank.

I would encourage you to first check the validation rule on the Lead object to see if the rule meets your expectations.